# XSL count number of nodes with parameter

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml :

```
 <pax>
     <age>5</age>
 </pax>
  <pax>
     <age>5</age>
 </pax>
  <pax>
     <age>12</age>
 </pax>
```

And the follwoing xslt:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="paxes/pax">
                <xsl:variable name="PaxAge" select="age"/>
                <COUNT>
                  <xsl:value-of select='count(paxes/pax/age[text()=$PaxAge])'/>
                </COUNT>
   </xsl:for-each>
```

However the result I get in count is always

```
<COUNT>0</COUNT>
<COUNT>0</COUNT>
<COUNT>0</COUNT>
```

If I  change  it to

```
<xsl:value-of select='count(paxes/pax/age[text()="5"])'/>
```

I will receive

```
<COUNT>2</COUNT>
<COUNT>2</COUNT>
<COUNT>2</COUNT>
```

The output should be:

```
<COUNT>2</COUNT>
<COUNT>1</COUNT>
```

How can I get the write count for each iterate?

Comment: What is the expected output? are you trying to count the occurrences of each age?

Comment: Are you sure that you are getting COUNT as 1?? According to me, w.r.t your current XSLT and XML, it should be 0..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to count the occurrences this should work,

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="age" match="/paxes/pax/age" use="." />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="paxes/pax/age[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('age', .)[1])]">
    <COUNT>

      <!-- optional -->
      <xsl:attribute name="age">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:attribute>

      <xsl:value-of select="count(key('age',.))"/>
    </COUNT>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

should give an xml like:

```
<COUNT age="5">2</COUNT>
<COUNT age="12">1</COUNT>
```

Comment: Good use of keys but the pattern and path `/paxes/pax/age/text()` could be shortened to `/paxes/pax/age` to simplify the expression without losing any functionality.

Comment: @MartinHonnen ah! I'm learning a lot of things by trying to answer questions. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You say you want one COUNT element in the output for each distinct value of age. That makes it a grouping query. In XSLT 2.0, you can therefore use the grouping query:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="paxes/pax/age" group-by=".">
  <COUNT><xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())"/></COUNT>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

If you're stuck with XSLT 1.0, grouping queries are much tricker, but you can use the technnique of Muenchian grouping with keys, as illustrated in the answer from @Rnet.